# Setting multiple activities in react native

Tags: android, react-native, android-manifest

I am trying to keep an absolutely positioned button in one place instead of pushing it up when the soft keyboard is in display. I have `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` set in my manifest. If I change it to `pan` or `adjustNothing`, I get my desired behaviour. But then again in another screen I have an absolutely positioned `text input` which I want to have it pushed up when the keyboard is in view, which on setting the manifest to `adjustNothing` or `pan` doesn't happen as RN has only one view in its manifest.

Is there anyway in react native to set multiple activities for different screens? If yes then an example will be helpful as I have already gone through https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2916 and its totally greek to me as I have zero knowledge of the native language.

If in any other way the following effect(***the start chat button simply staying at one place without moving up when keyboard shows***) can be achieved without touching the manifest is also welcome:

[image]

**UPDATE (Component Code):**

```
<Button
    icon={{name:"chat", size: 26}}
    title="START CHAT"
    raised
    borderRadius={50}
    containerViewStyle={uiTheme.button.container}
    buttonStyle={uiTheme.button.buttonStyle}
    fontWeight="500"
/>
```

**Note:** I am using react-native-elements and using a theme file which contains the following:

```
button: {
        container: {
            position: 'absolute',
            height: 55,
            minWidth: 55,
            bottom: 20,
            right: 0
        },
        buttonStyle: {
            height: 55,
            minWidth: 55,
            backgroundColor: COLOR.deepPurple500,
            paddingHorizontal: 16
        }
    },
```

Comment: wrap the views you want moved in a [`KeyboardAvoidingView`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/keyboardavoidingview.html) and leave the other views out of the `KeyboardAvoidingView`.

Comment: Tried, but didn't work. Maybe you can show me once again. Once I do, the button is removed from view completely

Comment: post the code for that component

Comment: @IshitaSinha, question updated

Comment: You didn't post the code for the whole `your_component.js` file. Which views have you wrapped inside the `KeyboardAvoidingView` and what `behavior` have you set to the KAV?

Comment: @IshitaSinha, I don't have the `KeyboardAvoidingView` set right now because I have been experimenting with various options. The whole component file is [here.](https://github.com/whimsicaldreamer/Aloha/blob/43b218486200b48de878df65be90bb73ba49ba7d/src/appComponents/recentChatList/recentChatListScreen.js#L163) I only want the button to be avoided by the keyboard.

Comment: Add the KAV around your button and set `behavior='position'`.

Comment: The button is removed from the view on doing the above recommendation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159129/discussion-between-ayan-and-ishita-sinha).